# How to sum values in a map efficiently within java

Tags: java, hashmap, sum

**DATA**

[image]

**CountryInfo**

```
public class CountryInfo {


    private String country;
    private String countryCode;
    private String currency;
    @Id
    private String state;
    private String stateCode;
    private String statePopulation;
```

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> getAllCountryPopulations(){
        List<CountryInfo> countries = countrySqlRepository.findAll();
        HashMap<String, Integer> populations = new HashMap<>();
        Integer sumOfPopulation = 0;
        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<countries.size(); i++){
            CountryInfo countryInfo = countries.get(i);
            set.add(countryInfo.getCountryCode());
            if(set.contains(countryInfo.getCountryCode())){
                sumOfPopulation += Integer.parseInt(countryInfo.getStatePopulation().replaceAll(",", ""));
            }
            populations.put(countryInfo.getCountryCode(), sumOfPopulation);
        }
        return populations;
     }
```

I am trying to return the sum of values for a given map on unique country codes.
Instead of returning the corresponding sum for each key in the set I am getting the sum of all values within the set.

Example:

```
{America: 4329392, Canada: 13025402}
```

Should be

`{America: 4329392, Canada: 8721010}`

How do I fix my logic here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your logic, the problem is

```java
Integer sumOfPopulation = 0;
```

should be defined inside your for loop as it will be different for each country.

Off-topic, you don't even need a set, a single HashMap will work here.

```java
final List<CountryInfo> countries = countrySqlRepository.findAll();
        final HashMap<String, Integer> populations = new HashMap<>();
        for (final CountryInfo countryInfo : countries) {
            final int sum = populations.getOrDefault(countryInfo.getCountryCode(), 0);
            final int population = Integer.parseInt(countryInfo.getStatePopulation().replaceAll(",", ""));
            populations.put(countryInfo.getCountryCode(), population + sum);
        }
        return populations;
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the total population of cities that belong to the same country, you don't need anything but the `Map` itself.

Variable `sumOfPopulation`, as well as `Set` are redundant. And also `if`-statement checking whether a particular code is present in the set after it has been added on the previous line.

You can use Java 8 method [`merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) to implement this logic:

```
public Map<String, Integer> getAllCountryPopulations() {
    Map<String, Integer> populationByCountry = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (CountryInfo country: countrySqlRepository.findAll()) {
        populationByCountry.merge(country.getCountryCode(),
            Integer.parseInt(country.getStatePopulation().replaceAll(",", "")),
            Integer::sum);
    }
    return populationByCountry;
}
```

The same can be done in a more concise way using Stream API.

For that we can use *collector* `groupingBy()` in conjunction with *collector* `summingInt()` as a *downstream*.

```
public Map<String, Integer> getAllCountryPopulations() {
    
    return countrySqlRepository.findAll().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            CountryInfo::getCountryCode,
            Collectors.summingInt(countryInfo -> Integer.parseInt(countryInfo.getStatePopulation().replaceAll(",", "")))
        ));
}
```

***Sidenote:*** don't use concrete classes like `HahsMap` as types in your code, leverage abstractions instead - write your code against interfaces. See [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)